# Ninject and trust level medium

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, ninject, medium-trust

I am trying to host my asp.net mvc 4 web app using hostgator. The problem at hand is the fact that the plan I am using only allows for the medium trust level. My application currently has the Ninject MVC package installed.

I have tried using the ".NET Framework 4.0 for medium trust environments" version of Ninject from Ninject's homepage, but alas no go.

Is there any way I can get Ninject 3.0 working with a medium trust level?

> The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the
>   security policy.  To grant this application the required permission
>   please contact your system administrator or change the application's
>   trust level in the configuration file.
>   System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.

Comment: perhaps I have installed the ".NET Framework 4.0 for medium trust environments" version wrong?

Comment: Please, expand on **not working**.

Comment: Updated post with exception.